# AWS DMS Converts Source PostgreSQL TIMESTAMP column to different value in S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, timestamp, aws-dms, dms

- DMS details:
- Source Endpoint is PostgreSQL DB.
- Target Endpoint is S3 - Parquet    file.

Source DB has a column `paymentdate` with datatype `timestamp`. There is a row with value stored as `0002-11-30 00:00:00.000` in the `paymentdate`.

When processed via DMS, above row is replicated as value `0003-11-30 00:00:00.000` into S3 parquet file. No transformation is applied for column as part of DMS definition (i.e. No Mapping rules defined for `paymentdate`).

This is observed only in case of specific case of this timestamp value. For rest of the values (i.e. Valid dates like `1993-11-30 00:00:00.000`, `2020-11-30 00:00:00.000` etc.) DMS is replicating properly.

How to handle such scenario? If possible, I do not want to apply transformation for `paymentdate` as it impacts downstream application too.

Comment: 1) 2020-11-20 00:00:00 is not a date it is timestamp. 2) 0002-11-30 00:00:00 is timestamp before timezones existed. Best bet is Parquet is doing a best effort to adapt it. 3)  If that is an actual payment date you have some really old bills.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. 1) and 2) 2020-11-20 00:00:00 and 0002-11-30 00:00:00 are timestamp only - same data type as the one problematic value . Corrected in question. Regarding 3) It is in fact not a valid value as per business rules. But just that somehow entered into the system. As the task is to just replicate value 'as -it-is' from source into S3, we want to bring such value into S3 for further processing.

Comment: Are you really saying you have payment dates for the year 2 AD?

Comment: That timestamp may be invalid as per business rule. But as part of replication process, we are expecting data to be replicated via DMS without changing value from the source.

Comment: This is a tech support question for AWS. Postgres does the correct thing: `select '0002-11-30 00:00:00'::timestamp; 0002-11-30 00:00:00`. Best guess is it is happening in the Parquet conversion. A quick search found multiple posts addressing timestamp issues with Parquet and S3.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, applying transformation into DMS to convert data type to `datetime` for the column resolved the issue.

```
{
  "rule-type": "transformation",
  "rule-id": "12345",
  "rule-name": "change-paymentdate-column-scale",
  "rule-action": "change-data-type",
  "rule-target": "column",
  "object-locator": {
    "schema-name": "public",
    "table-name": "tableABC",
    "column-name": "paymentdate"
  },
  "data-type": {
    "type": "datetime"
  }
},
```

Interestingly, earlier it was implicitly converted into S3 as `timestamp` only, but may be not able to handle all the dates.